# Jquery Rotate Img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to toggle an img (`.arrow-img`) in jquery to rotate.

Here's where I'm at;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".active-mobile").click(function() {
    $(".toggle-items").slideToggle();
    $(".arrow-img").css("-webkit-transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
    $(".arrow-img").css("transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
  });
});
```

As you'll see from the fiddle, this works the first time; but I need a way to reset/toggle it to return to it's original state.

I would also like to do this **without using** jQuery's `.addClass` method, I'm currently building a site using Squarespace, and that method doesn't seem to work in that environment.

Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/5q3zzygx/3/

Comment: i cant see anything happening in the fiddle

Comment: It's the little blue arrow I need to rotate beside Software Delivery, it only works the first time.

Comment: I've updated the link to make it more obvious Muhammad!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to check if the `style` attribute exists. When you call `.css` it puts an inline style on the element. If it exists then remove it, else add it.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".active-mobile").click(function() {
    $(".toggle-items").slideToggle();

    var $arrowImg = $(".arrow-img");

    if ($arrowImg.is('[style]')) {
      $arrowImg.removeAttr('style');
    } else {
      $arrowImg.css("-webkit-transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
      $arrowImg.css("transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q3zzygx/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your JS to just this rule, to toggle a class on the parent of `.toggle-items` every time you run `slideToggle()`:

```
$(".active-mobile").click(function() {       
  $(".toggle-items").slideToggle().parent().toggleClass("opened");     
});
```

Then add this CSS rule to transform the arrow to normal when the toggle is opened:

```
.opened .arrow-img {
  transform: none;
}
```

Simplest and cleanest way I could see of doing this. Demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".active-mobile").click(function() {
    $(".toggle-items").slideToggle().parent().toggleClass("opened");
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-wrap-mobile {
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(63, 70, 80, .15);
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.tab-list-mobile {
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tab-list-mobile li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: solid .5px #EEEEEE;
}

.tab-list-mobile li.active-mobile {
  border-top: none;
}

.tab-list-mobile li.active-mobile span.arrow {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.arrow-img {
  width: 15px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.opened .arrow-img {
  transform: none;
}

.tab-list-mobile li a {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
}

.tab-list-mobile li a {
  color: rgba(63, 70, 80, .5);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab-list-mobile li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(63, 70, 80, .95);
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.tab-list-mobile li.active-mobile a {
  color: rgba(63, 70, 80, .95);
}

.toggle-items {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-wrap-mobile">
  <ul class="tab-list-mobile">
    <li class="active-mobile">
      <a>Software Delivery</a>
      <span class="arrow">
          <img class="arrow-img" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59c51ac6268b96cf65b0125e/t/5a0455a9f9619aca282064c6/1510233513011/tab-arrow.png">
       </span>
    </li>
    <div class="toggle-items">
      <li><a href="/consulting">Consulting</a></li>
      <li><a href="analytics">Analytics</a></li>
      <li><a href="/training">Training</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vm63nj84/1/

I just added a new css rule for the arrow which animates it if it has the active class

```
.arrow-img.active {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

now I toggle this class with jquery:

```
$(".arrow-img").toggleClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and very clean approach is to a class with your transform, and toggle that class on click.

CSS:

```
.arrow-img.is-open {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

JS:

```
$(".arrow-img").toggleClass('is-open');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5q3zzygx/8/

Answer (score -1):

You can check the value of display for class toggle-items. If display is equal to none when clicked, you can set the rotation amount to the expected state.

```
if($(".toggle-items").css("display") == none){

}
else{

}
```

So use a variable to use for the amount of degrees insteads

Comment: Can the downvote be explained please? If the answer isn't good enough it'd be good to understand why for the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
var degrees = 0;
$(".active-mobile").click(function() {
  degrees += 90;
  $(".toggle-items").slideToggle();
  $(".arrow-img").css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
  });
});
```